# Need PowerShell help! Very strange things are happening

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

So I'm using PowerShell to manipulate a SharePoint 2010 library. I am uploading, downloading, and deleting files in a script using a custom module I made. My errors are so odd I can't understand them.I am using PowerGUI, Windows PowerShell ISE, and PowerShell Management Shell all in admin mode.

**PowerGUI:**

I sometimes can't get an spWeb object, sometimes I can. The URL string is being pulled from a CSV file so it never changes and neither does the code before I call `Get-SPWeb -Identity $correctURL`

Sometimes when I call a list `RootFolder` it returns `$false` for the `Exists` property, using management shell I can get past this. Otherwise I can touch it by calling `$ListName.RootFolder.Files` and it will magically return and hold the `$true` for `Exists` in future executions of my script.

Then when I call an XML file full of file properties(for uploaded files) it will return file property *names* for `$fileFieldsXML.row.Attributes | foreach {$_}` and *values* for `$fileFieldsXML.row.Attributes | foreach {$_.ToString()}`. This is, unless I set them to variables. When two very distinct vars are set to these two differentish calls they both are set to the array of property names! Why??

**Windows PowerShell ISE and PowerShell Management Shell**

I think these are just outdated somehow. I can call `Get-SPWeb` in Management Shell but I can't in ISE due to I guess outdated versions. Lately the management shell will act as if I haven't been doing anything to the files unless I close it out and reopen it. Does the management shell just hold a copy of all files when it starts or something? Can I make it update these files?

Can anyone suggest a better way to debug? Also why does a module seem to severely increase runtime? When everything was in the same script it was quick but my long functions take several times longer to execute now.

I also have been using PowerShell and SharePoint for almost two months now, so I am a beginner and intern. Perhaps that is really the cause of my problems :)

Comment: Don't have an answer as to why your seeing the strange behavior with things sometimes returning and sometimes not but as for ISE not allowing you to call Get-SPWeb have you added the sharepoint snapin/module to your session?

Comment: it's the first thing in my module `$spInstalled = Get-PSSnapin | Select-String Sharepoint
if (!$spInstalled){Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell}`

Comment: Interesting, and if you run `Get-PSSnapin` after that point does it show the SnapIn as being loaded?  If so what is the result of `get-help get-spweb`?

Comment: I've determined that the issue comes from a mixture of what I described about touching things before using them and the need to close the PowerGUI or whatever window and reload it before running whenever I make any edits, including line breaks! Well, not always but that's the only way to ensure these crazy errors don't occur

Comment: So what your seeing there is the fact that anything you assign to a variable in powershell is going to stay assigned until either the session is closed or the variable is assigned to something else.  to fix you an either set things to $null when you are done using them or use the "reset runspace" feature of PowerGUI to avoid having to close and re-open, altho neither of those are needed if you plan to only run the script from a fresh session in production.

Comment: Thank you, I just learned about the reset runspace this morning.